# Why does this public field have a PRIVATE flag?

Tags: scala, scala-macros, scala-reflect, scala-macro-paradise

I'm writing a Scala macro and am traversing the tree to find non-private fields in classes.

Consider this code that the macro looks at:

```
class Foo {
  val bar: String = "test"
}
```

I'm traversing this code and getting to `bar`'s `ValDef`. It has only two flags in its modifiers: `Flag.PRIVATE` and `Flag.LOCAL`.

Using the `private` modifier on `bar` changes nothing. Using the `protected` modifier only adds `Flag.PROTECTED` to the list of flags.

What am I missing? How do I make the distinction between private and public fields?

**Edit:**

The following code:

```
val bar: String = "test"
```

Has neither `Flag.PRIVATE` nor `Flag.LOCAL`, which makes sense since it's a 'global' public val.

The context I'm working inside is writing a new wart for [wartremover](https://github.com/wartremover/wartremover), which simply takes a `Traverser` from the context's universe when expanding the macro and traverses over the block of code.

Comment: Could you share your code so that we can play around with it ?

Comment: I could create a repro if you like, but the code I use is simply taking a Traverser from universe and running it on the code during macro expansion.

Comment: @Dici I've added more information and context to the question. HTH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `val` definition in Scala expands to a `private[this]` field with an additional getter. Other than the `ValDef` you're seeing there should be an additional `DefDef` method definition with the same name which is the getter on the field.